# Stop Process on Network Machine with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

In my project, I am going to do that :
There is a server in restaurant, and some pos machines which are running on Windows XP called Radiant systems. There will be a .exe on server, and this .exe will stop running some process on Radiant Poses. It is possible with .Net Remoting. But it requires to write an .exe on the Radiant Poses, but I dont want to do that. Think there is no problem on network access on Main Server in restaurant and Radiant Poses in restaurant. Is it possible to do that without using .Net Remoting?

Comment: If you do not want an EXE file on those systems, is a windows service an option?
How is the process that you want to shutdown being run? As an application, as a windows service or as web service?
You can access applications via remoting on another server (if the remote application is configured for remoting).

Comment: The process is an Application, and if you check article link posted by KMan, thats the all I need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be, to use [Remoting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307445) to call a KillProcess() method that would in turn call the [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method to kill a process. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_process_controller.aspx) is worth looking at.

Comment: I tested this application. Works fine, just be careful about Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a programming solution for this? Take a look at the command line tools that are available with Windows XP, namely the [`taskkill`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true) command. It allows to kill processes on a local or remote system.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> taskkill [/s Computer] [/u Domain\User [/p Password]]] 
>          [/fi FilterName] [/pid ProcessID]|[/im ImageName] [/f][/t]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following examples show how you can use the taskkill command:
>
> ```
> taskkill /pid 1230 /pid 1241 /pid 1253
> taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /im notepad.exe
> taskkill /s srvmain /f /im notepad.exe
> taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /p p@ssW23 /fi "IMAGENAME eq note*" /im *
> taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /fi "USERNAME ne NT*" /im *
> taskkill /f /fi "PID ge 1000" /im *
> ```

Comment: How you gonna execute these commands on Radiant System from Server?
I need a programming solution at that point.

Comment: When you are writing software that spawns a process on a remote machine and wants to kill that process before exiting, then you need a programming solution