# How to start/stop proccess on remote machine using C#?

Tags: c#, wmi, process

How to start/stop proccess on remote machine using C# ?
Remote computer is runing winXP sp3 and I have administrator account there. I always get access denied error. *Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))*

I am using C3 and .net 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked this question before. See my questions.

[Stop Process on Network Machine with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155654/stop-process-on-network-machine-with-net)

[Remote Process Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166090/remote-process-execute-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI automation http://www.dalun.com/blogs/05.09.2007.htm